# Server not reachable for HTTPS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, https, certificate

i'm trying for the first time to set up an own web site from front to end.
My problem is: I cannot connect to my server to http://mysite.de nor to https://mysite.de.
Goal: Enable the user to reach my server via HTTPS at all. All three input strings should lead to a https connection: my-site.de, http://my-site.de and https://my-site.de.

What have I done already?

1. I made a spring boot web application and rented a Strato VPS (Cent OS 8, but I also tried it on Ubuntu 18.04).
2. Used the Digicert CSR maker, the command it gave me was

- keytool -genkey -alias pvpfeedback -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore pvpfeedback_de.jks -dname "CN=pvpfeedback.de,OU=PvPFeedback, O=PvPFeedback, L=PvPFeedback, ST=PvPFeedback, C=DE" && keytool -certreq -alias pvpfeedback -file pvpfeedback_de.csr -keystore pvpfeedback_de.jks

2. I uploaded the csr to Strato (for a free SSL certificate from them)
3. Strato in return lets me download a .crt, a root .crt and an intermediate .crt file. I added the normal .crt and the root .crt to my .jks keystore

- keytool -import -alias pvpfeedback -file root_pvpfeedback.de.crt -keystore pvpfeedback_de.jks
- keytool -trustcacerts -importcert -alias pvpfeedback -file cert_pvpfeedback.de.crt -keystore pvpfeedback_de.jks

4. I placed all my stuff to etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors and update-ca-trust extract
5. I'm running my program with java -jar -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 pvpfeedback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Some additional stuff:

- I set up an Apache to verify that my site is registered, and indeed the default apache landing page was shown.
- Chrome give back a connection timeout error on http://my-site.de and https://my-site.de:
  [Website not reachable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH0FH.png)
- This is my very first post on this site, if I did something wrong please tell me.

When I start the spring boot app on the server, this is the feedback:

```
2021-02-20 18:00:09.341  INFO 19868 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https) 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-02-20 18:00:09.360  INFO 19868 --- [           main] c.e.pvpfeedback.PvpfeedbackApplication   : Started PvpfeedbackApplication in 6.042 seconds (JVM running for 7.72)
2021-02-20 18:00:09.559  INFO 19868 --- [   scheduling-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:75478}] to pvpfeedbackcluster-shard-00-02.xjveo.mongodb.net:27017
```

My Spring Boot Https configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HTTPSSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest()
                .requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class HttpToHttpsServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector getHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);

        return connector;
    }
}
```

```
server.address=<ServerIP>
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=pvpfeedback
server.ssl.key-store-password=<Password>
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:pvpfeedback_de.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.
I had to forward some ports in the firewall.
The following code snippet did the trick for me:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
```